# Should I load responsive design via JS or CSS

Tags: javascript, css, responsive-design

I am looking to make a slightly responsive design. I was curious to know how people feel on loading a responsive design, should I load in a new css file and use JS to define the screen size. Or should I create media queries inside the current css file and just go from there. Looking for opinion on speed and what people feel is the more optimal approach.

Comment: Questions on [SO] are expected to be about a specific code problem you're having. This question is asking for a discussion and doesn't have an objective answer.

Comment: My apologies, and thank you for taking the time to look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting everything regarding styles in the CSS files is the best practice.

- HTML => Structure
- CSS => Styles
- JS => Logic

The more you separate concerns, the easier your code will be to mantain.

Answer (score 0):

As javascript might be disabled you should use CSS-only for the responsive purposes.

If you really can't do without javascript (for moving an element in the dom for example) make sure that you've got some fallback css for non-js-enabled users.

Answer (score 0):

In fact very very few users will disable javascript, unless they are in emergency(say, if they only have outdated mobile phone because their new ones have run out of batteries). If your site is not toward these situations, use javascript without concerning that users will disable.

Generally, putting media queries in one css file will be a good choice if the file size is reasonalbe, since one file makes fewer request than seperated files.

Javascript, on the other hand, is the very fallback because old IEs do not support media queries.

You can refer to some frameworks such as [bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/). An implementation outdoes all answers.