# Is it always better to use CSS when possible instead of JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm wondering in what cases is this better to use JS when a pure css solution is possible. I've been browsing other questions but couldnt find the answer I was looking for.

Suppose we have images and want to display some stuff on hover. Should one use :

**Example :**

```
    $('div.some-class').mouseover(function(){
    $(this).children('.some-class').removeClass('hidden');
    });
```

or is this CSS solution better:

```
    div:hover > .my-elem{
    opacity:1;
    });
```

imho, the second solution is way better but i've been using the first one for couple of months and I just found out about the second one a week ago, so i'm not totally sure if it's a valid practice.

Comment: css is faster and sometimes can take advantage of graphics hardware, js tends to be slower. if you can implement in css it's better that way. (note that some fancy css stuff might have cross-browser issues)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Better or Worse: Styling with JavaScript vs CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19188419/better-or-worse-styling-with-javascript-vs-css)

Comment: For the above mentioned thing,  blindly go with css!

Comment: also the .hidden class would be better to change it globally in css instead of editing every single mouseover function, if there were hundreds

Comment: Maybe you don't mean `img:hover > .my-elem`, wich implies .myelement inside the img. You could use `img:hover + .my-elem`, wich refer to the sibling .my-element of img:hover http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html

Comment: Biggest difference is, if user disables his JavaScript, your layout will end up as a disaster, where as the one with the CSS won't

Comment: manipulating the DOM with JS is slower because you involve an API where with  css you just define the style of the html which is of course faster

Answer (score 8):

The CSS solution is better for 2 reasons:

1. CSS is loaded alongside the HTML, whereas JavaScript is loaded *after* the page itself has loaded. For things like a hover this isn't a huge issue, but if you're directly setting static styles you'll notice a delay between the content loading and the JavaScript running.
2. It's common for users to disable JavaScript. With JavaScript disabled, your `mouseover` function would never fire, whereas the CSS would work regardless.

However that said, `img` elements cannot contain children, so both your CSS and JavaScript is invalid.

Comment: Thanks you. Just one thing : is it really that common for users to disable javascript? most users don't even know what javascript is no?

Comment: @Radioreve users with plugins like [NoScript](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/noscript/) enabled would have to manually specify that they trust your website before the JavaScript would run.

Comment: @Mr.Alien http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/internals/howbrowserswork/.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly http://jsfiddle.net/Pdm77/ when the browser is parsing your html and if it hits a script block, it will start parsing js, and than it will continue with the rest of html, and thus sometimes you have to place the script before closing body tag

Comment: Just to add context, it depends where in the document your `<script>` tags are. If they are in the `<head>` and `$( document ).ready()` isn't being called, they will be parsed before (or whilst) the page / markup is parsed.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly I deleted the simple comment as mike pointed that it might sound harsh but I wanted you to know that it halts parsing and it doesn't execute at the end, it depends on where you place the scripts in your document :)

Answer (score -2):

**Case 1: Prefer CSS to JS**
1. CSS 3 is a mixture of CSS+JS and this enables you to develop your code faster rather than writing your own custom JS.
2. Prevents you from querying the DOM.
3. Loads alongside with your HTML (faster than JS)

**Case 2: Prefer JS to CSS**
1. This will help you when working with old browsers which don't have CSS3 support.
2. Helps you to handle other DOM functionality which CSS still doesn't have support. (for eg: you can change the color of some other element on hover of your element in CSS, but can't make any changes to JS variables or logic)

Comment: `CSS 3 is a mixture of CSS+JS` erm: no it isn't. In fact, I don't know what any of case 1 is referring to. Are you saying that css3 is _like_ a mixture of css and js (e.g. transitions)?

Comment: Yes, for example CSS:hover can enables you to carry out functionality like onmouseover and onmouseout together. CSS enables this blend. In simple words, CSS3 features will help you to remove most of your JS codes.