# When something can be done via JS or CSS, which way should I choose?

Tags: javascript, css, web, frontend

For example, I can use CSS to implement a navigation. And I can do that via JS too. And in many situations CSS and JS both perform well.

Which one is the good choice for web design?

Comment: always use css if its equivalent to the js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good rule of thumb is: *If you can do it with CSS, go for it.*

Philosophically, CSS should be focused on presentation and JavaScript should be geared more towards function.

Of course, **It depends**. While CSS is much easier to implement than javaScript in most cases, easier doesn't always translate to better. One good example are CSS animations vs a javaScript library like [velocity.js](http://julian.com/research/velocity/). You have far greater control over your animations and generally better performance across all devices with frameworks like velocity or [GSAP](http://greensock.com/gsap), but often it comes down to each individual project and which technology would make sense for your particular needs. Realistically, however, most projects will implement both technologies in the best cases where they fit. I hope this helps. For more info on this here's a link that does a great job explaining some of the differences when animating: https://css-tricks.com/myth-busting-css-animations-vs-javascript/ .

And here is a similar question with very good answers: [Better or Worse: Styling with JavaScript vs CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19188419/better-or-worse-styling-with-javascript-vs-css)